# 404 page while going to Admin CMS -> Pages

Tags: cms, 404-page

After deleting a store from admin, I am getting redirected to 404 error page when go to cms pages,
I have tried to solve this by Using the Query provided in magentocommerce thread
`DELETE FROM cms_page_store WHERE store_id NOT IN (SELECT store_id FROM core_store)`

There were some entries in that table which were related to the deleted store and deleted,
But the problem still remains.

Answer (score 2):

Database tables: core_website, core_store and core_store_group
    Look for website_id attribute in table core_website and delete that website id from this.
    Repeat same: core_store and core_store_group.

> You can check your store_view ids in admin->system->manage stores. All CMS pages should be assoicated with these id. If there is any extra/other id is in table cms_page_store field 'store_d' then 404 error will display.